# Struts 2 iterator not working in a JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2

The code below (part of a JSP) is not printing out anything, even though I know for a fact that there are members of the iterator that pass the test.  Any ideas?

```
<s:iterator value="bulletins">
    <s:if test="approved == true">
        <s:property value="name" /> -- <s:property value="subject" />
        <s:property value="date" />
        <br />
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure 'approved' is defined, and is named in a way that is accessible on the value stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might your IF test, not the iterator (which I'm sure works, and assuming you have bulletins to list).  The IF test language (expressions) can be tricky.  Try taking out the IF first, just to make sure you actually have data, then fix the IF test if need be.

Comment: Yes, it definitely was the if test.  Thanks.  I haven't figured out what the problem was yet, but I will work it out.

Comment: IMO, although there's a lot of capability with the expression language, the complexity and lack of good documentation on this has been an Achilles Heel with WebWork / Struts 2, so you're not alone. :-)